# how to make a ruby array be a x,y,z in an ActiveRecord prepared statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.20 and Postgres 9.4 on heroku and have the following fragement:

```
metro_area_ids=[3,4,7]
a=metro_area_ids.join(',')
self.where("metro_area_ids ilike '%-?-%' or metro_area_ids ilike '%-?-%' or metro_area_ids='%-?-%'", a)  # how to make this array be 3,4,7 joining doesn't work
```

I'd like to be able to pass an array of values from 1 to 10 (as an arbitrary upper limit) and be able to query against our table with a postgres ilike statement.

but I get

> ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid: wrong number of bind variables
>   (1 for 2) in: metro_area_ids ilike '%-?-%' or metro_area_ids ilike '%-?-%'

How would I make this work for an arbitrary number of inputs in the array?

## edit

so this doesn't work

```
Queryable.where("metro_area_ids ilike '%-?-%' or metro_area_ids ilike '%-?-%'",[1,13])
```

so this does work which is what I'm trying to simulate:

```
Queryable.where("metro_area_ids ilike '%-?-%' or metro_area_ids ilike '%-?-%'",1,13)
```

Comment: The first and the second condition look the same to me. What is the expected output?

Comment: what database do you use ? I think it's not possible with `LIKE` but probably possible with `REGEXP`. `ILKE` => Postgres, right?

Comment: definitely possible - I use Postgres 9.4 and will update question.

Comment: if you just need to reduce the error, remove `.join(',')` such the query should work. But it will not be work properly, for example if `id` will be the last element in field

Comment: thx @itsnikolay  - but to best of my knowledge, it doesn't. I have added in the above edit what I tried

Comment: What type of column is `metro_area_ids`?

Comment: it's a string that we dash and sort allowing for like / ilike statements to be used against it. so `-10--4--7-` or something

Answer (score 0):

This is because you reference many arguments through `?` while specifying only one (a string), use named placeholders or specify every element of the array alone.

using named placeholders

```
metro_area_ids={ st: 3, nd: 4, th: 7 }
self.where("metro_area_ids ilike '%-:st-%' or metro_area_ids ilike '%-:nd-%' or metro_area_ids='%-:th-%'", metro_area_ids)
```

provide each element separatly

```
self.where("metro_area_ids ilike '%-?-%' or metro_area_ids ilike '%-?-%' or metro_area_ids='%-?-%'", metro_area_ids[0], metro_area_ids[1], metro_area_ids[2])
```

Comment: `ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid: wrong number of bind variables (1 for 3) in: ` reads it as one argument

Answer (score 0):

you can simply test it by `$ ruby test.rb` and copy following content to the file

```
require 'active_record'

class Metro < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection adapter: 'sqlite3', database: 'foobar.db'
  connection.create_table table_name, force: true do |t|
    t.string :metro_area_ids
  end
end

Metro.create!([
  { metro_area_ids: '1,2,3,4' },
  { metro_area_ids: '2,3,4,5' },
  { metro_area_ids: '3,4,5,6' },
])
metros = Metro.where("metro_area_ids LIKE ?", "%2,3%")
p metros.inspect
#=> [#<Metro id: 1, metro_area_ids: \"1,2,3,4\">,
     #<Metro id: 2, metro_area_ids: \"2,3,4,5\">]
```

Comment: kinda of a different idea. doesn't handle noncontiguous

Answer (score 0):

What about like this:

```
Queryable.where("metro_area_ids ilike '?' or metro_area_ids ilike '?'", "%-#{1}-%", "%-#{13}-%")
```